# Acumatica adding new fonts to advanced report designer

Tags: acumatica

We have a customer with an invoice print layout that requires a specific font.  Is it possible to add new font type like Raleway to Acumatica report designer for invoices?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font can be selected in the name property of the report editor:
[image]

This lists fonts installed on the machine where report editor is executed. To handle custom fonts you need to install it on the developper machine and the server hosting Acumatica.

To install a truetype font in Windows simply drop the '.ttf' file in 'Windows\Fonts' folder. Restarting applications could be necessary to rebuild the font cache and make it available (this is application specific):
[image]

In Report Editor I suggest you set a global font in Report element if you want to set it as a default font for that report:
[image]

Make sure you have set PdfFontEmbedded to True otherwise system fonts will be used when viewing PDF.
[image]

Comment: As specified by Ilya, there's an option to embedded the font in the report. With font embedded in the report I think it's not required to install the font on the server hosting Acumatica instance, only on the report developer machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference in case others have a problem installing fonts on a windows 10 computer.

Issue: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings-winpc/does-not-appear-to-be-a-valid-font-file-can-not/d318e873-acb4-4796-8cc7-83149073d5bd

Solution: https://onlinefontconverter.com/